# Translation please Yiddish and roshai taivois about getting married fast

Tags: hebrew, marriage, translation

Please help me translation (understand)
[Igres kodesh 24 pg 227 (second paragraph)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15631&pgnum=264)

I understand the last line that

> "whoever shortens the time between the decision (to get married) and the marriage it is praiseworthy"

But I do not understand

> בימינו אלה הנה מכמה טעמים (כולל גם - דיר''ש) אינו ענין צו בינדען זיך ועאכו''כ א צווייטן - באם התכנית שהחתונה תהי' לאחרי זמן רב.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's "D'Yirat Shamayim"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My translation:

> In these days, for many reasons (including also - reasons of Yiras Shamayim [דיר"ש = דיראת שמים]) it is not a desirable thing to commit oneself and how much more so [ועאכו"כ = ועל אחת כמה וכמה] another - when the plan is that the wedding will be after a lengthy amount of time.